# How to retrieve distinct values from more than one column?

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have two columns of data. I'd like to run select statement on them that grabs all the distinct pieces of data in these columns 1 time. For instance.

```
*column 1*   *column 2*
dog          monkey
monkey       elephant
dog          monkey
```

I wanna be able to returna result set that has dog, monkey and elephant in it and that's all.

Comment: No actual answers to your problem but your table design might be a candidate for Normalization..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two selects:

```
Select column1 As c From t
Union
Select column2 From t
```

[`Union`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html) will take care of duplicates:

> The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following?

```
SELECT column1 unique_data FROM your_table
UNION
SELECT column2 unique_data FROM your_table;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (column1 varchar(50), column2 varchar(50));

INSERT INTO your_table VALUES ('dog', 'monkey');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES ('monkey', 'elephant');
INSERT INTO your_table VALUES ('dog', 'monkey');
```

Result:

```
+-------------+
| unique_data |
+-------------+
| dog         |
| monkey      |
| elephant    |
+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be lil dumb: `select distinct from (select distinct from first_column union select distinct from second)`  -  not valid sql, just logic

Answer (score 0):

Use [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), sample:

```
select 
    column_1 as name 
from Table_1
union
select 
    column_2 as name 
from Table_1
```

Output:
dog
elephant
monkey